# Where do I keep my passport

Tags: passports

How do you guys keep your passport when you are traveling overseas?  I am apprehensive about that and think it would be a better idea to take it along with me. But you are gotta beware the pick pocketers :D

Comment: Voting to close, no answer can be the right answer, sometimes you have to keep it on you as its required by that countries law, sometimes you don't have to, even then it's up to you what you want to do with it.

Comment: It depends a lot on the circumstances in the country, city, hotel, etc. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I used to store my passport and travel documents in [an orange folder](https://www.bookbindersdesign.com/images/2.16015/vavmapp-a4-orange-storlek-a4.jpeg). It makes it hard to forget and easy to spot and find. However, now my passport is in my carry-on, my Schengen ID in my wallet and my documents in my phone. Sometimes I have some good travel pants (where half the legs can be removed) with good pockets for the passport.

Answer (score 5):

Losing your passport in a foreign land can be a disaster. I have used a Go Secret Wallet, which hangs off my belt inside my trousers, to carry my passport for all my travels over the past 16 years and 65+ countries. I also keep my backup credit cards, emergency cash stash and spare passport photos in it. https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mjmSHuv4L.jpg